# New ibeacons not detected in my app

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am developing a beacon detection application and at the moment works very well for kontakt brand beacons.

The client has sent me some new beacons that i have never seen and I have searched with google but i can't find what brand they can be.

> The following information related to this beacon they gave me:

```
uuid: fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825
pass: 000000
name: ion_beacon00021
major: 16789
minor: 24532
```

[image]

I have transformed my code to monitor both uuid without making it work

```
for (index, beaconID) in beaconsIds.enumerated() {

  let beaconUUID = UUID(uuidString: beaconID)!
  let identifier = "BLERegionBeacon \(index)"

  let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID, identifier: identifier)
  self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
  self.locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}

func configureLocationManager() {
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager!.delegate = self
    self.locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager!.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager!.activityType = CLActivityType.automotiveNavigation;

    for region in self.locationManager!.monitoredRegions {
      self.locationManager?.stopMonitoring(for: region)
    }

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
      self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    self.locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

When not finding how to make this new ibeacon work I have resorted to third party applications (like `MyBeacon`, `Detector`, `Beacon Demonstrator`, `Locate`) to get validate if the information I have of this beacon is correct, but in no application I have been able to make it detect this ibeacon.

*I bought a new battery to make sure it was not as simple as that, but neither.* :'(

I had the idea to use any application that detects bluetooth devices and I found `BLE Scanner`. With this application i was lucky and could realize that at least the name that i have of the beacon is correct, but not found any related to `major or minor or pass`. I also thought that the long id seen there could be correct and that the I had was not... But I discarded it because when I connected the brand kontakt also gave me a different uuid.

[image]

[image]

`ISCONNECTABLE` Jumps between YES and NO.

When i use `BLE Scanner` to detect beacons `Kontakt` show me addional info called `SERVICEDATA` and `ISCONNECTABLE` still in YES.

[image]

**- Is there anything else that needs to be done to detect these beacons?**

**- Anyone have any idea what may be going on?**

Thank you very much

***EDIT***

Following the help of [davidgyoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461050/davidgyoung), I could realize that the Locate application if it works but only in its version for android. And in fact correctly returns the information I had been given from that beacon at first.

I found that these beacons with configurable using an application called [BeaconFlyer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/beaconflyer/id1062280457?mt=8) and there I realized the reason for being that password that had sent me. I was able to change the `uuid` although strangely I just put numbers and no letters. I changed it by 32 zeros following the same pattern of 8-4-4-4-12. I still get no results in IOS but works on android, even after changing the uuid.

It is possible that some brands need to be certified to be detected by iOS devices and that the android do not have these restrictions.

***EDIT 2***

Considering all these details, it seems that the problem is IOS and not android, so it occurred to me that maybe if I created a simple android project just to test the functionality of the beacons, I should be able to detect it.

The test was done by registering this UUID `f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e` which is the one that has always works for me and with which I detect without any problem the beacons mark`kontakt`.

To my surprise I detect it without problem even without registering the UUID that I have for this brand. It is very strange considering that only register 1 UUID that was the mark `kontakt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are detecting another beacon with the same code, then the simplest explanation is that **the ProxmityUUID you were given is wrong.**

You won't be able to determine the correct ProximityUUID from BLE Scanner on iOS, as iOS blocks access to iBeacon advertisements unless you know the ProximityUUID up front.   If you can get your hands on an Android device you can use the Locate app to see any beacon regardless of its identifiers. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en   You can use this to find out what it is actually sending.   There are similar apps for MacOS as well if you have access to a Mac.

Comment: hi david... Clinging to `the ProxmityUUID you were given is wrong`. Is very strange, because with the `Locate` application I could detect the kontakt mark without having to add the uuids previously.

Comment: If you are talking about Locate for iOS, then the reason it detects Kontakt out of the box is because the app is pre-configured to see Kontakt's default UUID.  I know because I am the author who put that into the app.

Comment: Hi, effectively the application you gave me if you detect this beacon ... and I could detect that the information I have from the beacon is correct, thanks. Now, by chance you know what is the reason that this beacon is not detected, however much I record this data in my application and also in third-party applications

Comment: OK, so have you confirmed if the ProximityUUID is what you expect?  Does Locate show the UUID as "fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825"?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that

Comment: OK, to clarify, your question says "but in no application I have been able to make it detect this ibeacon."  This is not consistent with the statement above "Yes, it is exactly that." in answer to my question:  "Does Locate show the UUID as 'fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825'?  Does Locate detect it or not?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the problem is that I do not edit that part in the question (I should have done it). `Locate` ANDROID APP shows me `fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825` as UUID of the beacon. But `Locate` IOS APP and any other application of IOS does not show me anything of that beacon

Comment: Just as a clarification, @davidyoung: Apple does *not completely* block the UUID for a beacon you don't know yet like you seem to think. It doesn't *recognize it as iBeacon* (and doesn't dispatch any region or ranging result regarding it to an app), but using the COreBluetooth framework you can still scan for it. You can scan for *any* bluetooth advertising devices that way. BLE scanner does exactly that, which allows you to inspect BLE devices. Unfortunately, it doesn't always properly identify devices, because it naturally doesn't know what they send.

Comment: @Gero, I wrote a blog post about this.  While it is true that you can get callbacks in CoreBluetooth for discovering iBeacons, if iOS sees that the advertisement format matches the iBeacon layout, it will actually nil out the advertising data.  So the callbacks are pretty worthless.  Read more here:  http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons

Comment: @davidgyoung Oh, that's very interesting. I've seen beacons for which I could get all the info with a scanner app (can't recall which one, though), but those were usually more sophisticated ones (you could e.g. edit their major and minor via bluetooth), so I guess they advertised another service and perhaps gave out the data that way. I haven't tried to use CoreBluetooth in that way myself, so it's interesting to know this limitation, thanks. One more reason, btw, to not use the cheapest beacons. :) (Oh, and the post also shows the "various uuids" aspect of this)

Answer (score 3):

It is quite clear that your client sent you "beacons" and not necessarily "**i**Beacons". As davidyoung pointed out, what constitutes an iBeacon is [specified (quite strictly) by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/). Download the specs from there and have a look, if you are so inclined.

I have used several BLE scanners to check what uuid, major, and minor numbers various brand iBeacons I worked with have, among them the mentioned BLE scanner. I think the specification does not prevent somehow putting additional services into an iBeacon, which results in different brand iBeacons potentially showing slightly different info in different scanners. 
However, what you show in the screenshot and the fact that the `isconnectable` field switches values make me think that these beacons are not correctly working.

There will be **no** way to make them work on iOS that way then. You can write your own Bluetooth protocol code to do stuff with them, but that then won't rely on Apple's iBeacon mechanics. This will mean the nice stuff like region monitoring even while the app is suspended and so on won't work. It's also probably more battery draining and in general more work.

---

I am as said not a Bluetooth expert, but learned this much: UUIDs are *all over the specs*. The UUID you (and Apple) refer to is a part of the *data packet* the iBeacon is supposed to send, but I have also seen BLE *services in general* being identified by UUIDs in (non-Apple) reference documents. This can get confusing when you scan such a beacon and see UUIDs (or at least strings that look like ones) in several places. So even if the beacons you have follow the spec (or can be configured to do so somehow) my guess is that someone screwed up. For example, they could have edited (maybe even with a hardwired connection and tool) the *wrong* UUID, not setting the one you need to use, but accidentally overwriting the part that specifies the device as an iBeacon (byte 5 and 6 of the data packet come to mind), making it impossible for you to use them.

As an advice I would suggest the following: If your client is interested in actual iBeacon functionality, tell them they should buy correct beacons. the kontakt ones are actually quite good. I've tested cheap china knockoffs and would advise against those, as they quickly become unreliable. It might be tempting to save a few bucks at first, but if you need to constantly replace beacons in the long run that becomes more expensive in the end.

Comment: In this case, the author of the question indicated that he was able to detect the beacons and parse them as the iBeacon format using an Android scanner.  It's one that I happened to write, so I know that it decodes them using the expected Apple iBeacon format, with the small difference that it is more tolerant of different manufacturer codes.   See my answer starting "One other theory about what might be happening" for details.

Comment: Well, that then verifies it, I'd say: It's a beacon, but not an iBeacon *as Apple wants it*. The manufacturer code (I assume you mean bytes 5 and 6 from the specification, right?) is supposed to be fixed, afaik. I've talked to people designing their own beacons when the framework just had come out and at first many though they were supposed to enter their own "company code", but it turned out it always needed to be 0x4C and 0x00.

Answer (score 2):

One other theory about what might be happening:

A beacon advertisement packet implementing iBeacon must have Apple's manufacturer code 004c in order to be detected by iOS.  Android has no such restriction.  If this beacon is sending a different manufacturer code it would explain why only Android can detect it.

How do you find out if this is true?  You need to see the raw bytes of the advertisement somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The beacon brand is Iotton and it's looks like the one we sell:
https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/ibeacon/ton9108

It's unlikely the Kontakt app is showing the Iotton beacon because the local name is incorrect. It's more likely your Kontakt beacon - turn it off for now. With this or any beacon, the best app for getting the UUID and seeing if the beacon is working is Nordic nRF Connect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have set the delegate on `CLLocationManager`?  The code doesn't show it, so unless this is somewhere above or below, you'll need to add:

`self.locationManager?.delegate = self`

Then make sure your class implements `CLLocationManagerDelegate` the `didRange(beacons: region:)` method to get callbacks.

If you think you already have this set up, showing that code might reveal something else that is missing preventing it from working.

Comment: of course. If that was not the case .. could not even detect the beacon mark kontakt. Check my code update